# what is the effect of *.mode1v3 file  in xcode?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I know project.pbxproje contain project file information.

*.pbxuser contain the information of the layout of some windows.

but I can't find what is the effect of .mode1v3.

if you some tip. thank you very much !

Comment: I have no idea, only [google](http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2007/Oct/msg00465.html): > They are your user-specific project settings: window states and geometry, breakpoints, custom executables, etc. You can choose to commit them or not; there's no harm or interference to other users if you do. HTH

Answer (score 2):

The .mode1v3 file contains user-specific project settings: window states and geometry, breakpoints, custom executables, etc.